# matche on lists

Tags: clojure, clojure-core.logic

I wonder if I can use something like matche to do pattern matching with a list in core.logic

With vectors something like

```
=> (defn checko [code r] (matche [code] ([['foo ?a ?b]] (== r [?a ?b]))))
=> (run* [q] (checko [:foo :u 2] q))
  ([:u 2])
```

works pretty well, but I could not figure out how to match a list (foo :u 2) instead of a vector. The reason is that I want to analyze clojure programs using core.logic.

Comment: Ok, I can just use
(defn checko [code r] (matche [(vec code)] ([['foo ?a ?b]] (== r [?a ?b]))))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checko should work just fine for matching lists.

Comment: Indeed it does. Whatever the problem was I cannot reproduce it. I will have to think it over again :-) Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

In case assurances from the author himself are not sufficient, I have used core.match and vector patterns match lists (and indeed seqs in general) just fine - that's what they're supposed to do.